# Prove that $(4^{502} - 3^{502})^2 + 4^{1004} \gt 2009^{182}$.

Tags: inequality

I tried to shift $4^{1004}$ to the right and use the factorisation of the difference of squares.
It gives, $(4^{502} - 3^{502})^2 \gt (2009^{91}-4^{502})(2009^{91}+4^{502})$. But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result derived actually helps. Note that
$$4^{502} = 2^{1004}=2^{11\cdot91+3}>(2^{11})^{91}=2048^{91}>2009^{91}$$
Hence the right hand side of the below equation is negative while the left hand side is positive.
$$(4^{502} - 3^{502})^2 \gt (2009^{91}-4^{502})(2009^{91}+4^{502})$$

Comment: yeah, right I missed that

Answer (score 1):

Only prove, $4^{1004} \gt 2009^{182}$

$4^{1004}=2^{2008}=2^{11\cdot182+6}=2048^{182}\cdot2^6>2048^{182}$

Now, $2048^{182}>2009^{182}\Rightarrow 4^{1004}>2009^{182}\Rightarrow  any\ positive\ number\ + 4^{1004}>2009^{182}$

Hence proved.

Comment: Right, its pretty simple, I just couldn't figure it out.